# MySql Latitude and Longitude

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there a fast way to calc the distance  between tow point lat and lng i have this code but it's slow

```
SELECT * FROM `hotels` WHERE (SQRT(POW(`lat` - 32.171253 , 2) + POW(`lng` - 35.057362, 2)) * 100) < 1
```

this return the points are in 1 km around

thank's in advance

Comment: that won't work. latitude-longitude are on a sphere, not a plane.... Do a search...

Comment: i did a search, what i find it like this work but slow.

Comment: @shyam i did not now that thanks , so what the equation to do this ?

Comment: IF the performance is more important than the accuracy in your case.  Why dont filter points in a square instead of in a circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DistanceKMFromLatLong
(
    @srcLatitude decimal(9,6),
    @srcLongitude decimal(9,6),
    @destLatitude decimal(9,6),
    @destLongitude decimal(9,6)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT DistanceKM = ACOS(SIN(PI()*@srcLatitude/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@destLatitude/180.0)+COS(PI()*@srcLatitude/180.0)*COS(PI()*@destLatitude/180.0)*COS(PI()*@destLongitude/180.0-PI()*@srcLongitude/180.0))*6371        
)
GO
```

Ref: [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

You use it by joining to two tables containing the source and destination lat/longs as follows:

```
select 
    p.Latitude,
    p.Longitude,
    s.Latitude,
    s.Longitude,
    DistanceFromStoreKMNew = d.DistanceKM
from
    Staging.PostcodesToLatLong p 
    join dbo.Store s on s.StoreId = p.StoreId 
    cross apply dbo.DistanceKMFromLatLong(p.Latitude, p.Longitude, s.Latitude, s.Longitude) d
```

You could also create a scalar valued function from the haversine formula.

If you want it faster, create a CLR stored procedure.

Comment: ok, but could you provide how to use , like how to set lat and lng and what the result in mile or km ,, ?